# Prompt in zsh starts with ↑255 after an error command?

Tags: zsh

I'm new to zsh and am using the ZSH_THEME="jnrowe", which works great for a little while.

It starts out and I get a prompt that looks like this:

```
Ξ ~ →
```

but if I run a command like: `ssh` it becomes:

```
↑255 ~ →
```

I suspect something is messing up the character that was creating the triple bar in the first one, but have no clue really as to what's going on. I could just pick a different theme, but I've noticed most of them with a fancy character in the prompt do the same thing.

Is this a special error code or something? Or is something just borking out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the prompt theme "jnrowe" (it's not part of the default zsh distribution afaics), but I suspect this prompt includes the error code of the last command in its output.

Try to run "ls" or "true" and the number will disapper. Run "false" and it will be 1, run ssh without arguments and it will be 255. zsh preserves this value until you run the next command, so pressing ENTER many times will not clear it.

(This will be the same value that is stored in the shell variable "$?")

Comment: That's what it is. so how do you actually use that information or retrieve a description of what that error code is?
Also, jnrowe is bundled with oh-my-zsh -> https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/themes/jnrowe.zsh-theme

Comment: Return values are not well-defined. Only 0 = everything okay, everything else = something may be wrong... Oh, and 139 may be a SEGFAULT, since signals are represented by the return value 128 + signal, but a program could return this value to represent something else :( Programs that are often used in shell scripting have their return values documented in their man page